# How to call two view from same function in controller on different state using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to call two different views from same function (function index) in controller.

I have passed one argument (an id) to index function that time I want to show all the list of blog when id's value is null and if I get an id then I want to show only one blog that's id is in url.

And I have successfully done this but I get shown a warning:

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
> Message: Missing argument 1 for blog::index()
> Filename: controllers/blog.php
> Line Number: 5

How can I resolve this?

My code:

```
class blog extends CI_Controller{

function index($url)
{
    $this->load->model('blog_model');
    $url = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $data['blog_details'] = $this->blog_model->getBlog($url);
    $data['blog_comment'] = $this->blog_model->getComment($url);
    $data['blog_all'] = $this->blog_model->getBlogAll();
    $this->load->view('blog',$data);
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better define a default value for the variable you are expecting to get:

```
function index($url = NULL){
```

This will make your function to set the `$url` as `NULL` in case there was not argument passed to the function in the URL.

```
function index($url = NULL)
{
    $this->load->model('blog_model');
    //$url = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $data['blog_details'] = $this->blog_model->getBlog($url);
    $data['blog_comment'] = $this->blog_model->getComment($url);
    $data['blog_all'] = $this->blog_model->getBlogAll();
    $this->load->view('blog',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must check get id is null or not and the you must load the view upon on that.

Example:

```
function index($url)
    {
        $this->load->model('blog_model');
        $url = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if($url == null){
          $view = 'blog';
          $data['blog_all'] = $this->blog_model->getBlogAll();
        }else{
          $view = 'blog_details';
          $data['blog_details'] = $this->blog_model->getBlog($url);
          $data['blog_comment'] = $this->blog_model->getComment($url);
        }
        $this->load->view($view,$data);
    }
```

But a better way to do it in the routes.php, declare different methods for each route.

```
$route['blog/:any'] = 'blogs/blog_details';
$route['blogs'] = 'blogs/all_blogs';
```